# How to change center of object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgpoint

This is the code I'm using to center my button to the bottom of the screen:

```
CGFloat centro = self.view.center.x;
CGFloat bottom = CGRectGetMaxY(self.view.frame);

_sendButton.center = CGPointMake(centro, bottom);
```

However, the actual center of the button is set to be at the bottom of the screen, which covers half the button. How can I set it so that the very lowest point on the button is set to:

```
CGPointMake(centro,bottom)
```

instead?

Comment: You now its height and width, calculate the desired center based on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subtract half the height of the button:

```
CGFloat centro = self.view.center.x;
CGFloat bottom = CGRectGetMaxY(self.view.frame) - _sendButton.frame.size.height / 2.0;

_sendButton.center = CGPointMake(centro, bottom);
```